# How to register middlewares in OctoberCMS plugin?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, octobercms, laravel-middleware

[Registering middlewares in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware#registering-middleware) is easy:

> simply list the middleware class in the $middleware property of your
>   app/Http/Kernel.php class

or

> If you would like to assign middleware to specific routes, you should
>   first assign the middleware a short-hand key in your
>   app/Http/Kernel.php file

But how can this be done in an OctoberCMS plugin? Is the "[Routing and initialization](http://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/registration#routing-initialization)" meant to be used in place of `Kernel.php` to register middlewares? If not, where can a plugin register its own middlewares?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Documentation](http://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/registration#registering-middleware) you can extend the controller class inside the the boot method of your plugin.php ;

```
public function boot()
{

    // Extend Controller Class
    \Cms\Classes\CmsController::extend(function($controller) {
        $controller->middleware('Middleware\Path..');
    });


    // OR Push it directly to the Kernel

      // prependMiddleware : Add a new middleware to beginning of the stack.
     $this->app['Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel']
        ->prependMiddleware('Middleware\Path..');

     // pushMiddleware : Add a new middleware to end of the stack.
     $this->app['Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel']
        ->pushMiddleware('Middleware\Path..');

}
```

Also you can add it in your plugin's `routes.php` file :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'foo'], function () {

        Route::get('{slug}', function($slug){

           ....

        })->where('slug', '(.*)?')->middleware('Path\To\Middleware');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it working using the 'middleware' option with a fully qualified class name with a Route group in my plugins routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => '\Namespace\ABC123\AuthMiddleware'], function(){
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
Cms\Classes\CmsController::extend(function($controller) {
$controller->middleware('your middleware here');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can push a middleware on your plugin `register` callback because it's registered before middleware happen.

```
class YourPlugin extends PluginBase
{
   public function register()
   {
    $kernel = app()->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel');
    $kernel->pushMiddleware(YourMiddleWare::class);
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to list the middleware class

```
$middleware property
```

of the Kernel.php class.